# Does http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle only work on English?

Tags: tags, share

My website supports both zh_CN and en_CA, when I use the following two urls to share on linkedin.
Only English version works(can show og:title/image/description), but linkedin does not work on zh_CN link. Maybe linkedin scraper does not support UTF-8.

BTW, when I post zh_CN and en_CA on facebook, both works fine.

http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://leifang.ca/p/contact.html?locale=zh_CN
http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://leifang.ca/p/contact.html?locale=en_CA

When I access my zh_CN link from browser, my og tags have the following values:

```
<title>联系方式⋅蕾</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="联系方式⋅蕾"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="/images/leiContact180x110.png"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="本着客户利益是第一位的原则。帮助您決定投資或保险的最佳方法。我期待着与您的会面。"/>
```

When I access my en_CA link from browser , my og tags have the following values:

```
<title>Contact⋅Lei</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="Contact⋅Lei"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="/images/leiContact180x110.png"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Follow Putting The Customer First principle. I look forward to meeting you."/>
```

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

I sent this link to my friend who is working in linkedin.

Seems he forwarded this problem to their internal team.

I tested again this morning(2014-11-29), linkedin fixed their problem. :)

Comment: I have a similar problem. When I use shareArticle in language Dutch or French, linkedin deletes everything after the "#" sign. So when I share a url "http://test.com/#/testPage/2", only "http://test.com/" is shared. This works fine when my language is set to english on linkedin. Can you ask your friend about this problem? Thanks! :)